# include typescript file in output result build with TFS

Tags: tfs, build, copy, typescript, output

I want to have ts files in output result.
when tfs build my project all ts file will compiled but just js files copy to drop folder or output.
I need ts files in published web sites, but I could not copy them with TFS Build.
I have seen this link [How to include TypeScript files when publishing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24322063/how-to-include-typescript-files-when-publishing/26164426#26164426)
but It dose not work for me.
When I add each ts files as a content in csproject, that files copy to bin folder as a result.
but it's hard to do for all type script files and I tjink it isn't good approch.

Comment: Is there anybody to help me?

Answer (score 0):

So after many work, I found the problem
Actually this link work correctly:[How to include TypeScript files when publishing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24322063/how-to-include-typescript-files-when-publishing/26164426#26164426)
but in my csproject there is a strange thing, we have multi import tag and I found the order of theme must be as the following:

```
 <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
 <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets')" />
 <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
 <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
```

In the other hands the Microsoft.CSharp.targets import tag MUST be the first to include type script files as content worked correctly.