# Chrome showing blank TypeScript file

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-2013, typescript, source-maps

I am setting up a new TypeScript project in visual studio 2013.

I have the option on my VS project to generate source maps checked. I have the option to specify root directory for typescript files and specify root directory for sourcemap files unchecked.

I have the option in Chrome Dev tools to enable JS sourcemaps checked.

At the bottom of my generated app.js file I see:

```
//# sourceMappingURL=app.js.map
```

And that file exists.

I do not see the source maps being downloaded in the network pane, and when I open the .ts file in the sources pane, I just see a blank file.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Try deleting the .js and .js.map files and regenerate the javascript code again and try to run again. Sometimes the map files get corrupted.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Place this in your web.config to serve up the TS files:

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".ts" mimeType="application/x-typescript" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 6):

Cordle's answer worked for me, but I also needed to remove the existing MIME map for .ts.

```
    ...
    <system.webServer>
        <staticContent>
            <remove fileExtension=".ts" />
            <mimeMap fileExtension=".ts" mimeType="application/x-typescript" />
        </staticContent>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The default MIME map for .ts files was "video/vnd.dlna.mpeg-tts".

Comment: this was perfect. thanks for the details on default ts mapping

Answer (score 3):

I figured out what was going on. I needed to add a mime map for the extension `.ts` either in IIS or in my web.config. So the browser was asking for the TypeScript file but not getting anything back, therefore it showed up blank.

Comment: This explained why it worked for me in Chrome "out of the box" whilst another developer had to add the mimeMap to our web.config file. I already had a ".ts" mime type entry in IIS but the other developer didn't.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, finally figured out that I had listed a SourceUrl

```
//# sourceURL=CommonLib.js
```

at the bottom of my Ts Script, which caused the folder of the Map and Ts file to be different.

Answer (score 0):

Add MIME to 
web.config:
    
OR IIS.

Answer (score 0):

If it works on `localhost` but shows blank after publishing to any environment it is probably due to that the `.ts`-files are not included.

To include `.ts`-files on `Debug` publish add this at the bottom of the web `.csproj` where the other `<Target Name` are. If you wan't `.ts`-files on every publish remove `Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'"`.

```
<Target Name="AddTsToContent" AfterTargets="CompileTypeScript" Condition="'$(BuildingProject)' != 'false'">
   <ItemGroup>
      <Content Include="@(TypeScriptCompile)" Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Debug'"/>
   </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Source:
[How to include TypeScript files when publishing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24322063/how-to-include-typescript-files-when-publishing/26164426#26164426)