# How to deploy an angular2 application as a webapp in azure

Tags: azure, angular, azure-web-app-service

Can someone help me deploy an angular2 application as a webapp in azure. I have a github enterprise setup. On my Jenkins server, I would like to do a no build. On successful completion of the build, I'd like to push it to a webapp.

Every deployment I attempted, failed on npm of one form or other. I don't want to create a VM and deploy a server.

I'd appreciate any help on this.

Comment: please refer to question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37487046/deploy-angular-2-with-azure-webapp/43119936#43119936

Answer (score 2):

Deployment of all supported web applications to azure web app service ( PaaS and not IaaS VM as per your requirement) is possible by the following options

1. from git CLI you can publish the code from your local repository to azure.
2. linking an online repository like bitbucket, gitlabs to azure
3. Powershell - publish code from your local repository to azure
4. Azure CLI - publish code from your local repository to azure
5. [FTP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-deploy-ftp) option is available as well.

Check out this post to see how you can publish using git commandline https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/app-service-deploy-local-git

Comment: Don't forget FTP :-)