# How to deploy angular2 to azure?

Tags: angular, azure, azure-web-app-service

I'm a beginner, I want concrete explanation.

I'd like to deploy Angular2 basic project to Azure Web/App service.

I have finished Azure setting and deployed it to my github repository.
and By angular cli, I have created angular2 project.

ng new ~~
npm i
ng serve -o

finally, I don't know how to deploy this folder to my azure.

Comment: this might be useful https://stackoverflow.com/a/43119936/4382557

Comment: https://sajeetharan.com/2020/02/14/deploy-angular9-app-to-azure-with-github-actions/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build your application by using the following cli command:

```
ng build
```

There are a lot more parameters that you can use with this, you can read about them [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build).

Running the build will produce a new folder called `dist`. The content of this is what you need to deploy to Azure, or to any other cloud service / server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to build your application by using the following cli command:
`ng build --prod`
build will create a new folder called dist.Copy files in dist and paste it to server folder.It will works..

Answer (score -1):

Step : 1
Install Angular cli

```
npm install -g angular-cli
```

Step:2
Create a project by using Angular-cli

```
ng new myApp
```

Step:3

```
cd myApp
```

Step : 4

you can use http-server to serve your app .

```
npm install http-server -g
```

Step : 5

```
ng build --aot
```

it is going to copy everything from source code to dist folder

step 6 :

```
http-server dist/ -p 80 > .output.log &
```

it will serve all the files in your folder. you can check the terminal what ip-address and port you can use to access the application. Now open up your browser and type

```
ip-adress:port
```

Hope it will help you :)

Answer (score -2):

I wanted to **share an easy way to publish Angular application to Azure**.

Background: angualar2 combo web api project native asp.net project

Answer: publish main project that was not complete until I took two steps

1. right click on app directory holding angular2 files and menu publish
2. show all files and right click on node directory and menu publish

Until I did 1 and 2 all I got was a blank index html page.
hope this helps someone.

Comment: Does nothing for me! It has to do something with production ready angular app.