# Publish Angular-CLI 6 ASP.Core application to Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core-2.1, angular-cli-v6

First of All here some Info

- Project Angular-CLI ASP.Net Core 2.1
- Publish from Visual Studio to Azure WebService

So what i have tried.

I have a running SPA in visual studio it runs fine without any error or warning.
Now i want to publish it to Azure over the build in publish via Visual Studio.

The publish Job show every thing is ok, then i go to the site where it should be hosted.

Now i get the following error:

[image]

so there is no complete error message why it was crashed i have found some logfile of the starting of the application:

> 2018-07-10 16:55:17.799 +00:00 [Information] Starting web host
>   2018-07-10 16:55:20.691 +00:00 [Information] Azure Web Sites environment detected. Using '"D:\home\ASP.NET\DataProtection-Keys"' as key repository; keys will not be encrypted at rest.
>   2018-07-10 16:55:22.456 +00:00 [Information] Starting @angular/cli on port 50808...
>   2018-07-10 16:55:25.208 +00:00 [Error] npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\ClientApp\dist\node_modules\start\package.json'
>
> 2018-07-10 16:55:25.716 +00:00 [Information] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost/
>   2018-07-10 16:55:28.285 +00:00 [Warning] Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
>   2018-07-10 16:55:28.301 +00:00 [Error] npm ERR!  { [Error: ENOENT, open 'D:\home\site\wwwroot\ClientApp\dist\node_modules\start\package.json']
>
> 2018-07-10 16:55:28.575 +00:00 [Error] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
>   System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: )) ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: ) ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was:  ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(String sourcePath, String npmScriptName, ILogger logger)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(String sourcePath, String npmScriptName, ILogger logger)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.<>c.b__2_0(Task`1 task)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__278_1(Object obj)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Util.TaskTimeoutExtensions.WithTimeout[T](Task`1 task, TimeSpan timeoutDelay, String message)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Proxy.SpaProxy.PerformProxyRequest(HttpContext context, HttpClient httpClient, Task`1 baseUriTask, CancellationToken applicationStoppingToken, Boolean proxy404s)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.SpaProxyingExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: ) ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was:  ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(String sourcePath, String npmScriptName, ILogger logger)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(String sourcePath, String npmScriptName, ILogger logger)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.<>c.b__2_0(Task`1 task)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__278_1(Object obj)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was:  ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(String sourcePath, String npmScriptName, ILogger logger)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(String sourcePath, String npmScriptName, ILogger logger)<---
>   <---
>
> 2018-07-10 16:55:28.974 +00:00 [Information] Request finished in 3267.6338ms 500 text/html; charset=utf-8
>   2018-07-10 16:55:41.654 +00:00 [Information] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://xircuitportal-beta.azurewebsites.net/
>   2018-07-10 16:55:41.790 +00:00 [Error] An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
>   System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: )) ---> System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: ) ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was:  ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(String sourcePath, String npmScriptName, ILogger logger)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(String sourcePath, String npmScriptName, ILogger logger)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.<>c.b__2_0(Task`1 task)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__278_1(Object obj)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Util.TaskTimeoutExtensions.WithTimeout[T](Task`1 task, TimeSpan timeoutDelay, String message)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions.Proxy.SpaProxy.PerformProxyRequest(HttpContext context, HttpClient httpClient, Task`1 baseUriTask, CancellationToken applicationStoppingToken, Boolean proxy404s)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.SpaProxyingExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was: ) ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was:  ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(String sourcePath, String npmScriptName, ILogger logger)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(String sourcePath, String npmScriptName, ILogger logger)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.<>c.b__2_0(Task`1 task)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__278_1(Object obj)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>      at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot)
>   ---> (Inner Exception #0) System.InvalidOperationException: The NPM script 'start' exited without indicating that the Angular CLI was listening for requests. The error output was:  ---> System.IO.EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(String sourcePath, String npmScriptName, ILogger logger)
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.AngularCli.AngularCliMiddleware.StartAngularCliServerAsync(String sourcePath, String npmScriptName, ILogger logger)<---
>   <---
>
> 2018-07-10 16:55:42.383 +00:00 [Information] Request finished in 728.6751ms 500 text/html; charset=utf-8

The sort of the log: it says that he tried to find the file `D:\home\site\wwwroot\ClientApp\dist\node_modules\start\package.json`

But the folder doesnt exsist and the package.json is in the `ClientApp\dist` folder.

All my configuration says that the output of the build is going to `ClientApp\dist`

So what configureation must i set, that the angular app is running in azure

Here my package.json (the start)

```
{
  "name": "ClientApp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "serve": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "run": "ng build",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  [...]
}
```

when your need more info of one file or config write it in the comment i provide it than.

Comment: Have u installed the angular cli in kudo? check this answer out https://stackoverflow.com/a/43119936

Comment: i have tried that but now im struggle with an other error when i build the app. Now azure build the app and says command `'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like:

```
services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });
```